# How to get all each value from the dynamic view in android to perform calculation

Tags: java, android

I've encountered a problem to get all the values from my dynamic view. I need all of the value from each row so I can get the right answer for my calculation. For now, the output for the calculation only read the last value that input by the user and give me the wrong answer. I've tried several solutions but they are not working for me. I really appreciate your help since I'm not an expert.

[this is the picture for my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO8Iu.png)

```
 int valueActLength = Integer.parseInt(actualLength.getText().toString());


    for (int i = 0; i < parentTableLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View row = parentTableLayout.getChildAt(i);
        EditText lengthInput = row.findViewById(R.id.length_input);
        EditText inputQuantity = row.findViewById(R.id.input_qty);
        int inputQty = Integer.parseInt(inputQuantity.getText().toString());
        int requireLength = Integer.parseInt(lengthInput.getText().toString());
```

//this is the code for creating new row

```
public void addView() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View w = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rod_input, null);
    parentTableLayout.addView(w);
```

**I've solve the problem. Thank you**

Comment: We need to see the code you use to create a new row each time

Comment: I've already added it.